# Overlay Images using ImageMagick (6.9.9.18) Version and Knitr (Version 3.4)

Tags: r, image, imagemagick, overlay, r-markdown

I am trying to create a report in R Markdown (Version 1.0.153, Mac OS X 10_13_1) with an html output to embed multiple MRI images of the brain using a vertical scrollbar, but also overlay certain images.

I am very new to coding so am not sure how difficult my problem is, or if the packages I'm currently using work together.

Currently, I am using the function knitr::include_graphics to display my images when knit to HTML, and css styling. I have 4 jpg images that I can currently scroll through using the following code in R markdown:

````
<div class="vscroll-plot">
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align="center"}
library(knitr)
knitr::include_graphics('1.jpg')
knitr::include_graphics('2.jpg')
knitr::include_graphics('3.jpg')
knitr::include_graphics('4.jpg')
```
</div>
````

With the CSS style:

```
.vscroll-plot {
width: 910px;
height: 600px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

My question is, how can I use ImageMagick to overlay jpg 1+2, and jpg 3+4, while still maintaining the scroll function (between the 2 resultant images). Is this possible using both knitr (Version 3.4) and ImageMagick (Version 6.9.9.18)? Is there another tool I should be using?

Any help is appreciated, as the link I've described previously was above my level of understanding. Thank you.

Comment: The [magick](https://github.com/ropensci/magick) package wraps ImageMagick quite nicely so you can do this all from R instead of going to the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you possibly provide an example, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What you want isn't really clear, but [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#combining) pretty much covers how to join, layer, and otherwise manipulate images.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide and example input pair and what you want the overlay to look like (an example).